# How to store control characters in MySQL DB through C++ code?

Tags: c++

I have a requirement. In my project I need to store control characters (ASCII characters range from 0 to 31). But here I need to store in the form of characters. I wrote a c code, but it not worked. I'm posting here the code what I wrote.
My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 and I'm using MySQL Connector C 6.0.2

```
     #include "stdafx.h"
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string>
     #include<my_global.h> 
     #include <mysql.h>

     using namespace std;

     MYSQL* Connection, MySQL;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int i;
string sData;
char SQLString[384];

for(i=0;i<=31;i++)
    sData+=i;

    char *Hostname="localhost", *Username="root", *Password="system123", *Database="file_data"; 

mysql_init(&MySQL);
Connection = mysql_real_connect(&MySQL, Hostname, Username, Password, Database, 0, 0, 0);

if (Connection == NULL)
    exit(1);

sprintf_s(SQLString,384,"set sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';");    
mysql_query(Connection, SQLString );

sprintf_s(SQLString,384,"insert into file_values(first_data)values('%s')",sData.c_str());
mysql_query(Connection, SQLString );
    return 0;
    }
```

Here, before writing actual project code, I wrote a sample application to test is it able to store or not, but by using above code I'm not able to store the control characters in first_data column of file_values table.

The data type of first_data is varchar of size 33.

Plz let me know the changes what I need to do in above code to acheive my requirement.

Thanks one and all.

Comment: Maybe blob field could help you, its designed to store binary data.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use prepared statements for this rather than trying to embed your character codes in a string.  You'd also might be better using a blob data type rather than string.

Here's an (untested) example of how to store a blob using a prepared statement:

```
MYSQL_STMT* statement = mysql_stmt_init(Connection);
std::string statementStr = "insert into file_values(first_data) values (?)";
mysql_stmt_prepare( &statement, statementStr.c_str(), statementStr.length() );

MYSQL_BIND parameter;

parameter[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB;
parameter[0].buffer= (char*)sData.c_str();
parameter[0].is_null= 0;
parameter[0].length= sData.length();
mysql_stmt_bind_param( statement, &parameter );

mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
mysql_stmt_close(statement);
```

Alternatively, if you need to stick with a varchar for the column type you could probably just replace the buffer_type above with `MYSQL_TYPE_STRING`